# CoreData/SQLite fastest way to determine if a field doesn't end with a particular string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, core-data

I'm using CoreData backed by SQLite and I'm trying to find the fastest way to exclude rows where the field AirDate ends with -00-00

I've noticed that

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT AirDate CONTAINS %@", @"-00-00"]
```

is much faster than

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT AirDate LIKE %@", @"*-00-00"]
```

Are there any other optimizations that I can make?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT AirDate CONTAINS %@", @"-00-00"]
```

Was the fastest in my tests, so that's what I went with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regular expression:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT AirDate MATCHES %@", @"-00-00$"]
```

But you probably should use `NSDate` instead of storing the date as a string. It should be faster to search using date comparisons instead of matching strings.